# V-model of TimePicker can't be set to any value

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Playground example:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=dZAlXG&v=10

It's not possible to set a value to `v-model`, If you log it will say that is that value. But the UI don't change. It's not possible. I also tried to use `:hour` and `:minutes` but that is even worse.

Playground example: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=dZAlXG&v=7

What I want is that when you press the button `now` that he will change the time to the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think it's the issue with the initial value you are setting on `selectedTime`

```
this.selectedTime = moment().format("LT");
```

TimePicker works with Date object, but you are setting the initial value to a string, using a Date helps v-model to function as expected

```
this.selectedTime = moment().toDate();
```

Comment: It works, but it's not usefull, that you need at the date object to the time. If you use the `DatePicker` you can even use `moment().format('L')`. But it's still no reason why the `:minutes` and `:hour` don't work

Comment: There is no reason why it should actually work, you have used v-bind on `minutes` or `hour`, it serves the purpose already. It would set the hour & minute on time picker but it won't take the changes back unlike v-model. Only `time` property supports v-model.

Comment: If you try it, just wait one minute to pass. Then press now in the `:minutes` and `:hour` button. It will change to the time. But it will only change on time per minute.  But I don't understand why I need to give a `date object` to an `timepicker`. If I use `datepicker` I can set it by this `07/04/2019` is equal to the date.